# Lp graph theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Let $X=X\left(V,E\right)$ be a graph. Let $f$ be a function on $X$. Let $1\leq p<\infty$. If we define $L^{p}\left(X\right)$ to be the set of all functions $f$ on $X$ such that $\|f\|_{p}^{p}=\sum_{x\in V}\vert f\left(x\right)\vert^{p}<\infty$, is this a Banach space under this norm? If it is, how can we prove it? Can you give me a reference where can I find this topic?

Comment: This is just the $L^p$ space on the discrete measured space $X$ with the counting measure. It is a Banach space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say there is nothing graph-theoretic about this question. You take the free vector space on (the vertices or the edges? of) $X$ and then consider the $L^p$-subspace of it. You should simply consider a reference which explains measure theory to you, as the theory of $L^p$ spaces is already very rich.

Hope that helps,